# Google instant search header gap issue

Tags: browser, google-search

I'm having this weird problem with Google these days. When I search a term/phrase in instant search, there appears a white gap between the search box and the results section. I'm upset with this as this acts as a barrier for faster surfing on the web.

[image: https://flic.kr/p/FksNDY]

Comment: Could you grab a screenshot and add it in?

Comment: Actually, it happens sometimes. I'll try to do it the next time. ASAP

Comment: What Browser are you having the issue in? and have you tried another browser to see if it does it there too? Trying to isolate the issue.

Comment: My guess is Firefox have a look at this [Link](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/927968) same issue you are facing.

Comment: I'm currently using Google Chrome. It happens to me on Firefox too.